# Python: website's class prints out an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape everything in the class `stats` (`item price` and `price changes`) with the following script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/Dragon+warhammer/viewitem?obj=13576" 

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

price = page_soup.find_all(class_ = "stats")

print(price)
```

I get this print:

> []

I used this script for all my other webscrappes and it's the first time I get something like that.

I tried looking around, asked some people, I still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of *page_soup* variable:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"></script><script src="/Criciousand-meth-shake-Exit-be-till-in-ches-Shad" async></script></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=30&xinfo=7-5532445-0%20NNNY%20RT%281620414344651%2056%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%201%29%20r%281%20-1%29%20B12%2814%2c0%2c0%29%20U5&incident_id=1233000410021120939-28775082668132935&edet=12&cinfo=0e000000d694&rpinfo=0&cts=UC3pkO3NyZP9f4EA4%2fm56lwz1Y6BhOV6CwF4xNVSeeeNp96DzLjUUDt3%2b5RYEDst" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1233000410021120939-28775082668132935</iframe></body></html>
```

if you visit the website in incognito mode you will see the same result.

As the page does not have a class named 'stats', the result of the *page_soup.find_all(class_ = "stats")* is an empty list.

Comment: When I inspect it on Chrome, the HTML code shows me :

<div class="stats">

    <h3>
         "Current Guide price"
        .....

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You tried in an incognito window? In my first visit, i had to solve a captcha. Only after solving the captcha all content are loaded

Comment: Yes. I tried in incognito mode and it doesn't ask for a captcha. That's weird. What do you think I could do from there?

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem with site parsing may arise due to the fact that when trying to request a site, it may consider that this is a bot, so that this does not happen, you need to send `headers` that contain [`user-agent` in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), then the site will assume that you are a user and display the information.

If the first method did not help, you can try using [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on. A good idea will be also to combine rotated proxies with rotated user-agents which will minimize the chance of being blocked.

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-securerunescape-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

data = []

html = requests.get("https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/Dragon+warhammer/viewitem?obj=13576", headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

current_guide_price = soup.select_one("h3 span").text
today_change = soup.select_one("li:nth-child(1) .stats__gp-change").text
one_month_change = soup.select_one("li+ li .stats__change--positive .stats__gp-change").text
three_month_change = soup.select_one(".stats__change--negative .stats__gp-change").text
six_month_change = soup.select_one("li:nth-child(4) .stats__gp-change").text

data.append({
  "Current Guide Price": current_guide_price,
  "Today's Change": today_change,
  "1 Month Change": one_month_change,
  "3 Month Change": three_month_change,
  "6 Month Change": six_month_change
})

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "Current Guide Price": "29.6m",
    "Today's Change": "110.8k",
    "1 Month Change": "475.0k",
    "3 Month Change": "- 4.3m",
    "6 Month Change": "- 18.5m"
  }
]
```